# Code First Navigation Property 1 to 1 Relationship with Two Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following classes:

```
public class ParticipantAssignment
{
    [Key]
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public int WorksitePositionId { get; set; }
    public int WorksiteId { get; set; }
    public int EmployerId { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignDateTime { get; set; }

    [Not Sure What Attribute to Use Here to Create the Relationship]
    public ProgramWorksite ProgramWorksite { get; set; }
    ... removed ...
}


public class ProgramWorksite
{

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int WorksiteId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    ... removed ...
}
```

There is a 1 to 1 relationship between ParticipantAssignment and ProgramWorksite.

I'd like to be able to relate the `ProgramWorksite` navigation property in the `ParticipantAssignment` class to the `ProgramWorksite` class.

However, if you notice, the relationship would be based upon two fields in both classes, the `WorksiteId` and the `ProgramId` - not quite sure how to do this.

**One thing to note...**

The code above APPEARS to be working, but i'm not certain if its actually using the "ProgramId" in the relationship, as the relationship could be made with the WorksiteId alone - it would supply a record however it wouldn't be accurate without factoring in the ProgramId

Comment: i think you have to use fluent api to solve the problem.

Comment: Yea - i wouldn't be surprised, I just haven't had much luck searching google, i'm not really even sure how to describe my question in a single search phrase, the phrases I used so far haven't brought up relevant results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so - I was able to profile the SQL being generated using [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) and it appears that with the current setup above it is correctly using both the `ProgramId` and `WorksiteId` in the join.